# create next + previous button on same html with lots of sections

Tags: html, button, linked-list

I create a static html
with

27 section id(s)
like this -->

```
    <section id="001">
    <h1>Chap 1 Summary</h1>
    /* lil content */
    </section>

    <section id="002">
    <h1>Chap 2 Summary</h1>
    /* lil content */
    </section>

    <section id="003">
    <h1>Chap 3 Summary</h1>
    /* lil content */
    </section>
```

...etc

---

and for each section the style/css is like this:

```
#001, #002, #003 ---go on {
    background-color: #97CACD;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

can I make 'Previous' and 'Next' button for each current/focused section that link to the previous/next section?

so far I know is creating specific 'next' and 'previous' button, that linked like this.

For example, I'm currently seeing Section #002,

```
    <section id="002">
    <h1>Chap 2 Summary</h1>

    /*---content---*/


    <div id="button_previous"><a href="#001">Previous</a></div> 
     /* to go back to section #001*/

   <div id="button_next"><a href="#003">Next</a></div> 
    /*to go next to section #003 */

    </section>
```

^ but that requires I write the targeted href link on every section manually.
is there any other option that doesn't require manual writing on the href?

sorry for bad english
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery and something like:

HTML: 
`<a class="prev-link">prev</a>`

JS:

```
$('.prev-link').click(function() {
    location.hash = '#' + (parseInt($(this).parent().attr('id')) - 1);
});
```

It should work if you use id "1" instead of "001".